# setInterval() start from the begin again

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, function, for-loop

When any movement, function A() start. Then function B() also start and repeat every 10 milliseconds. But if have any movement again, function A() start again and i need to function B() also start from the beginning. But until complete the past 'for' loop in function B() doesn't start again even function A() start again. I don't know how to do this... Is there any way to do this?

```
function A() {
            // Code block - make a queue

            setInterval(function B(){
                // For Loop using above queue
            },10);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearInterval could remove setInterval object.

```js
var c;
    document.getElementById('AA').addEventListener('click', A);
    function A() {
      // Code block - make a queue
      clearInterval(c)
      let i = 0;
      c = setInterval(function(){
        i++
        // For Loop using above queue
        console.log(i)
      }, 100);
    }
```

```html
<button id="AA">aaa</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Even i use this, It doesn't helped to resolve the problem in my code [link](https://github.com/JayashankaAnushan19/Death-Maze-) _Clear past path and go on new path_ - **from line 490**. I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: when clearInterval(c), he just stop setInterval object. in your game, maybe create a function to clearInterval(c) and reset all state and path to beginning or your wish. them call setInterval(B,10) to restart?